# How to install PHP 7.1

Tags: raspbian, php

Title pretty much says all. I know about adding the *stretch* to get PHP 7. But it doesn't show PHP 7.1.

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

*Bonus question* where should I drop the request to update the default PHP version of Raspbian?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package `php7.1` isn't in the `stretch` repo, but it is in the [`buster` and `sid` repositories](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=php7.1) (for Debian 10 and unstable, respectively).

You should be able to just change `stretch` to `buster`, and then run:

```
$ [sudo] apt-get install php7.1
```

You may find it helpful to upgrade your system as recommended in the [Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) when doing this using `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` — **be aware that this will upgrade your entire system from stable to testing**, and many packages are likely to be upgraded.

---

On to your bonus question:

> Where should I drop the request to update the default PHP version of Raspbian?

The default version of PHP in Raspbian is extremely **unlikely to be changed** for now, because of the [way that Debian's release cycles work](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases#Release_statistics):

> In the above array, data closely following "current" releasing tendencies have been highlighted in green. What can be deduced from those data is that the "most-typical" Debian release:
>
> - endures a freeze cycle of 7 +/- 1 months before getting released.
> - is released about 2 years after the previous one (the often cited example of Debian Sarge being quite an exceptional event in Debian history).
> - leaves users about 1 year to upgrade to the next one once this latter itself gets released.
> - has (from release to the end of security updates) a total lifetime of about 3 years.

Stretch was frozen [in February 2017](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch), so there will be no new feature updates to the PHP package in the Stretch repositories. So, for the foreseeable future, the PHP package will remain outdated in stable until Raspbian [Buster](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBuster) becomes stable (at which point, the PHP package there will become outdated, ad infinitum).

It's just the nature of Debian: you trade away the newest packages in exchange for greater stability, and you'll have to stick to the testing release if you want the latest features.

Comment: I've used the lower prio and only install with the `sudo apt-get install -y -t stretch php7.0....` to prevent from having stretch on other components.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me with instructinos of [Heidi's Lab](http://www.heidislab.com/tutorials/installing-php-7-1-on-raspbian-stretch-raspberry-pi-zero-w):

1. In `/etc/apt/sources.list` change `stretch` to `buster`, which is the next-stable/testing repository.
2. Update System `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. Remove previous PHP `sudo apt-get remove '^php.*'`
4. Install PHP 7.1 `sudo apt-get install php7.1-fpm php7.1-cli` or `sudo apt-get install php7.1`