# Unable to install php7.2-intl Depends php7.2-common 7.2.4-1 but 7.2.4-1+b1 is to be installed

Tags: raspbian, php, apt, raspbian-buster

While trying to install a NGINX server on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 I was following [this](https://janw.me/2017/installing-php7-2-rapsberry-pi/) tutorial, also tried [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70388/how-to-install-php-7-1) but both return the error 
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.2-intl : Depends: php7.2-common (= 7.2.4-1) but 7.2.4-1+b1 is to be installed`. [The Debian Buster Repository also lists](https://packages.debian.org/buster/php7.2-intl) that php7.2-intl depends on 7.2.4-1+b1 . I have not been able to figure out a way to tell apt that it should forcefully continue. Hopefully someone knows why this is happening and how I can solve this.

Comment: From a deleted answer: *It's a head ache, but I am working on it myself. I found a helpful post if you only want to run 7.2. If you want 7.0 and 7.1 on the same server, it doesn't seem to work correctly, yet.

[Raspberry Pi Dev Setup with Nginx + PHP7](https://getgrav.org/blog/raspberrypi-nginx-php7-dev)

The link above works for having **just** 7.2 installed.*